# How to control the bounce speed in uiscrollview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

Is there a way to ensure that the bounce back happens after a delay (say 1 sec) of the user lifting their finger. During this intervening delay period, the view should still respond to other user interactions.

Comment: I would use content insets to allow the user to scroll outside of the content size. Then override layout subviews is a subclass (don't forget to call super). If the scrollview stops with an offset outside of this wait one second. If after the second the scrollview hasn't moved. roll your own bounce animation.